# Add spacing between digits and non digits

Tags: swift

Hi guys I have a probelm that I needed to solve. Here are the examples:

**input is `ABCD12345` will output `ABCD 12345`**

**input is `A12345BCDE` will output `A 12345 BCDE`**

**imput is `ABC   12345` will output `ABC 12345`** (excess spacing removed)

As shown above a single spacing shall be added when there are no spacing but if there is, it will check if there are double spaces, then it will make it into single spacing.

Comment: Anything you tried so far? And what about symbols, punctuation, quotation marks, ....?

Comment: This seems like a 'do my homework for me' kind of question...

Comment: Actually I have look around and look for regex for this (since I'm not good at it) but I only found to separate by either digits or non-digits, not both.. It's up to anyone wants to help, if you don't want to help so be it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what you ask you can do something like this:

```
let letters = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()
let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
var res = ""
var lastDigit = false
for char in [input].unicodeScalars {
    if letters.longCharacterIsMember(char.value) && lastDigit {
        res += " "
        lastDigit = false
    } else if digits.longCharacterIsMember(char.value) && !lastDigit {
        res += " "
        lastDigit = true
    }
    if String(char) != " " {
        res += String(char)
    }
}
print(res)
```

In the code above you should replace the `[input]` placeholder with the input that you want to deal and the result string will be in `res` variable.

Comment: Thanks! I hope this could help others as well